# "Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed" error message

Tags: asp.net, transactions

A client of our has recently upgraded a ASP.NET 1.1 web application to ASP.NET that uses COM+ transaction processing and received the following exception while trying to process a transaction:

> Exception Type: 
>   System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException
>   Message: Communication with the
>   underlying transaction manager has
>   failed.
>
> Inner Exception Type: 
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   ErrorCode: -2147467259
>   Message: Error
>   HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from
>   a call to a COM component.

Here are the following settings on MSDTC Security Settings:

> -- Network DTC Access
>   -- Allow Inbound
>   -- Allow Outbound
>   -- Incoming Caller Authenication Required

A Windows XP SP3 workstation is trying to establish a connection to a Windows Server 2003 machine.

Has anyone else experienced this error and know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to have network DTC access enabled on both your XP workstation and your windows 2003 machine. Also, if your application is only published internally, you can turn off incoming caller authentication and set it to "no authentication".

Comment: Cool...I will compare the settings on the server against the settings on my workstation.

Comment: Thanks for for the answer.  I just had to change "Incoming Caller Authenication Required" to "No Authentication Required"

Answer (score 9):

Add C:\Windows\msdtc.exe to the firewall exceptions on both the firewall and server. I spent ages monkeying around opening specific port numbers and ranges to no avail before I did this.

Comment: On Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter it was at c:\windows\system32\msdtc.exe.

Answer (score 3):

1)Disable authentication besides enabling the network access to "distributed transaction co-ordination " service
(mutual authentication doesn’t work as displayed in internet in xp sp3 machines)

2) enable network access in client ( web applicaton ) and server ( sql server ) machines for "distributed transaction co-ordination " service .

Answer (score 2):

You'll also need to make sure your firewall is open for ports 135 and 5000-5020.

See these:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/71f7a219-c85d-4a04-973b-c73464f59606/
http://blogs.msdn.com/florinlazar/archive/2005/09/16/469064.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/architecturegeneral/thread/7731d7a7-a9ad-42e7-b0bb-f3656b870304/
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596/

Answer (score 0):

In case you need help finding the MSDTC settings mentioned in the other answers (like I did), the following link explains how to configure MSDTC on server 2003.

http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/how-to-configure-dtc-on-windows-2003/